# How can I know the node name for my running job on slurm

Tags: linux, hpc, slurm

Is there is any command that will return the node name and the details for my running job on the cluster that uses slurm scheduler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`squeue`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html) should provide this information directly via the `-o` option. To get the allocated nodes, the corresponding format specifier is `%N`, thus for example to retrieve this information for a job with id 1000:

```
squeue -h -o "%N" -j1000
```

Or to request this for all jobs of a particular user:

```
squeue -h -o "%A %N" -u user_name
```

Here, `%A` returns the corresponding job id. The `-h` option removes the header in the output...